# jQuery ui datepicker does not load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to display the datepicker when page loads

`$("#dp").datepicker("show")`;

but it is not working.

Comment: Could you add more explanations and some code ;) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call the attach function only after the document has finished loading (otherwise you could be trying to attach to a dom element that doesn't yet exist).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dp').datepicker('');
});
```

Also, make sure you have referenced the JQuery library correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Or try using Microsoft's or Google's CDN-hosted versions:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#dp").datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Can i do this with 2 datepickers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to previously have attached the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show):

```
$("#dp").datepicker();
$("#dp").datepicker("show");
```